# How does Error work in Swift in Xcode 8 beta 4

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta4

Seems like when converting our old code to beta 4, I keep casting Error to NSError.  That will even lead sometimes to a warning "conditional cast from 'Error' to 'NSError' always succeeds".  I feel like I'm not understanding how best to use Error.  I want to get to thinks like error.code, error.localizedDescription...  Is there good documentation or tutorials that explains these Error changes?

For example:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
```

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
if let error = error as? NSError {
 if error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
```

But that gives the warning "Conditional cast from 'Error' to 'NSError' always succeeds"

Comment: Error is bridgeable to NSError in the same way that String is bridgeable to NSString.  I.e (error as NSError) would work.

Comment: Would you mind marking an answer as correct if it ended up helping you?

Comment: I don't think these answers are right, and I think it is a beta 4 issue.

Answer (score 35):

Error is bridgeable to NSError in the same way that String is bridgeable to NSString.  I.e (error as NSError) would work.

```
if  (error as NSError).code == NSURLErrorCancelled { 
    // code
}
```

Comment: FYI: just tried to cast my own `enum MyError : Error { case test }`. The result: `nsError.code` prints `0`, `nsError.domain` prints `MyError`, `nsError.localizedDescription` prints `The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyError error 0.)`

Answer (score 22):

Do this:

**Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.0**

```
if error._code == NSURLErrorCancelled { }
```

Comment: I hate it when a language comes with "features" like that

Comment: I wouldn't rely on something undocumented. It could be changed without warning and your app will break.

Answer (score 4):

Error catching in Swift 3 has changed. Search for NSError in [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html). Quote:

> Additionally, error types imported from Cocoa and Cocoa Touch maintain all of the information in the corresponding `NSError`, so it is no longer necessary to `catch let as NSError` to extract (for example) the user-info dictionary. Specific error types also contain typed accessors for their common user-info keys. For example:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(", options: [])
} catch {
    // error is of type NSError already
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: How would I deal with this? 

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {

Right now I'm doing something like 

  if let error = error as? NSError {
            if error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {

But that gives the warning "Conditional cast from 'Error' to 'NSError' always succeeds"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is accurate. `error.code` is still not accessible, and alt-clicking `error` will show you that it's still inferred to be of the `Error` type.

Comment: @Jason the issue you're having is using `error as? NSError` instead of `error as NSError`. Error can always be casted to NSError so you don't need to use a conditional cast (i.e. `as?`) because it will always succeed (which is exactly what the error is telling you).